# How to call a lua cfunction from another lua cfunction?

Tags: c++, recursion, lua, backup, callstack

I am writing a lua (5.1) extension for our application that allows our customers to extend it with further screens without our support.

In general this works very well and with the help of a dozen of wrappers even very comfortably, but now I got following situation:

I have got two user data objects, an object Timer and an object Window.
The user can "attach" events to them by simply defining theirs members OnTimer and OnSizeChanged.

This still works very well:
mainLoop (C++) -> check all timers (C++)-> script object attached ? (C++), then:

```
// get ud by reference / stack: +1 / 1
lua_rawgeti(mState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, miReferenceId); 
lua_getfenv(mState, -1); // get attached table / +1 / 2 total
lua_getfield(mState, -1, functionName.ToChar()); // +1 / 3 total
if (!lua_isfunction(mState, -1))
{
...
}
lua_remove(mState, -2); // remove table / -1 / 2 total
lua_remove(mState, -2); // remove ud / -1 / 1 total, just function remaining
// ( .. user data still pushed at this point ..)
lua_pcall(mState, 1, 0, 0);
```

So in following scenario everything is still perfectly fine (stack definitely 0 before initiating the call and afterwards):

```
function OnTimer(Self)
Log("Some text") // Log calls C++ luaLog with 1 argument
end

myTimer = timer.new()
myTimer.OnTimer=OnTimer;
```

If the lua script looks like this though:

```
timer = timer.new()
window = window.new()

function OnTimer(Self)
   window:SetSize(323.5,234.5)   
end

function OnSizeChanged(Self,NewWidth,NewHeight)
Log("Sized changed")
end

timer.OnTimer = OnTimer
window.OnSizeChanged = OnSizeChanged
```

Then the callstack in C++ will be:

```
timer::HandleTimer (C++) -> 
push "OnTimer"  function ->
push timer ud -> 
pcall (L,1) -> .. (Lua) 
static int luaChangeSize(lua_State *L) (back to C++) ->
Window::SetSize -> 
The window sees "oooooooh, an event handler has been assigned" -> 
push "OnSizeChanged" function, window ud, x, y -> 
pcall(L,3,0,0) -> .. (Lua) -> 
int luaLog(lua_state* L) (back to C++ again)
```

Of course at the point where OnSizeChanged shall be called the stack still contains the content of the previous luaChangeSize callback and is not empty.

I thought I could simpy clean the stack by popping all the arguments of luaChangeSize before calling the Window::SetSize and restoring them afterwards, but this doesn't work. The result is a bit random depending on the constellation of the call stack, from "cant call a number" to randomly calling a previous function on the stack again. (the gettop is definitely 0 before and after all calls).

So: How can I "backup" the current stack and restore it afterwards as lua does it itself in a C++ -> Lua -> C++ constellation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of backing up and restoring the stack seems wrong. Can't you just leave the stack how it is and let the new call work on top of the existing stack. Make sure everything accesses items on the stack using a relative to top index rather than absolute.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and yes, I thought about this fallback solution as well already and it would be possible by attaching some sort of StackOffset variable to our own script instance object, which could then be used get the the "real" argument count like argumentCount = StackOffset-lua_gettop(L).

The problem is that all extensions not written by us (such as luasocket) which still rely on gettop to verify the argument count would not work.

Just curious if there is a "clean" way which would let a recursive c call behave as if it had been called from a lua script.